# save results from one api in different arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an action in pinia which I do a get to an api where I get some elements, the api returns the pagination with the current page, elements per page, total pages and total elements, the get only returns 20 elements for each Every time I call the action, when I load a component I call it and it returns the data (20 elements) and I save it in an array to then go through it and show it in cards, I have a button where I call the get action with the page in +1 to bring the other 20 elements. I am trying to get all the elements when loading my component, the way to get them all would be by clicking on the button which would return 20 by 20, but how can I make it so that when loading the component it calls all the elements without affect the array that goes from 20 to 20 and save them in a different array? In an array I save 20,40,60..., but in the other I would save the total elements.

```
>action
    fetchElements(query = "", params) {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.loading = true;
            const index =
              stage_amp === undefined || stage_amp === "dev"
                ? client.initIndex("req-dev")
                : client.initIndex("req-prod");
            index
              .search(query, params)
              .then(({ hits, page, hitsPerPage, nbPages, nbHits }) => {
                hits.forEach((hit) => {
                  this.elements.push(hit);
                });
                this.pagination = {
                  page: page,
                  perPage: hitsPerPage,
                  totalPages: nbPages,
                  totalHits: nbHits,
                };;
              });
          });
        },

>I get the first 20 elements
getElements.fetchElements();

>button that brings me the other 20 elements
const pagination = () => {
 getElements.fetchElements(query, { page: getElements.pagination.page + 1});
}
```

pensaba

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you want a way to get the 20 elements from the current page, but you still want to fetch all the elements ?

There several ways to this, but the simplest (in my opinion) would be to have an array of all your pages, and an index to keep track of your current page.

For example, the structure may look like this :

```js
// In your store
const state = () => {
  elementsPages: [
    [...], // elements from page 1
    [...], // elements from page 2
    [...]  // elements from page 3
  ],
  currentPage: 0
}
```

That way, you could have 2 differents computed, one to get only the 20 elements from your current page, and one to get all the elements

```js
// in your component
export default {
  computed: {
    currentPageElements() {
      const allPages = this.$store.state.elementsPages
      const currentPage = this.$store.state.currentPage
      return allPages[currentPage]
    },
    allElements () {
      return this.$store.state.elementsPages.flat()
    }
  }
}
```

This works assuming that `elementsPages` is always an array, and `currentPage` is an Int between 0 and `elementsPages.length`. The code is just a simplified sample that you may need to adjust to fit your needs.

This is, in my opinion, a good way to manage your store state since you will not duplicate your data (meaning that you don't have a property that contains the first 20 elements, AND another property that contains everything)

Also, note that the `elementsPages` property is an **array of arrays**. Instead of :

```js
hits.forEach((hit) => { state.elements.push(hit) })
```

You may need to use something like this :

```js
state.elementsPages.push(hits)
```

Hope that helps ;)